# Slide one view over another

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a view controller with page view controller at the top and a table view at the bottom. When I scroll up the table view I want the table view frame to slide up to the top of the screen and back to the bottom of the page controller view when I scroll down.

- The table view slides up to the top of the screen but the table view cells also scroll. See the first video link.

I want only the frame to change and the table view cell to scroll until it reaches the top of the screen.

[**video for what I achieved**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CYUble7uecHFhYvqNyoXKNJ_ZLX6WUcn)

[**video similar to what I want to achieve**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fxbjObK38O7fL68onJ8rsKz8-09YXlpP/view?usp=sharing)

In my sample, I tried changing the NSLayoutConstraint attached to the top of the table view in scrollViewDidScroll.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //the height of the pageview controller
    //the height and width of the pageview controller is the screen width.
    CGFloat yPos = self.pageViewHolder.frame.size.height;
    //content offset as I scroll
    CGFloat offset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
    //to place the tableview exactly below pageview controller view
    if (offset < 0) {
        offset = screenSize.height - screenSize.width;
    }
    //to place the tableview frame fixed on top of the screen
    else if (offset > yPos) {
        offset = screenSize.width;
    }

    //to slide the table view above page view by changing the NSLayoutConstraint anchored to the top of the table view and the super view.
    CGFloat difference = yPos - offset;
    self.tableViewTopGap.constant = difference;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Why won't you put the tableView as a sub view over the background, and add PanGesture to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable and disable scrolling on the table view until it's at the top of the screen.

So in the code that you posted above there, you're checking to see where the table view is in the if else statement, you should enable and disable scrolling in there.

When you don't want the table view to scroll: `[tableView scrollEnabled: NO];` and then when it's hit the top of the screen just set that to `YES`

Comment: The content offset won’t change I guess if I set scroll enabled to NO..

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. Yes, the content has to do with scrolling within your table view. So as the table view itself moves up and down, you need to check the position of its frame to determine where it is in the window. 

When its y position is greater than 0 you know it isn't at the top, so the table view should have its scrolling disabled. Then when its y position is 0 (or less I guess with scroll bouncing) then you can enable scrolling in the table view